# Directly assign results of doMC (foreach) to data frame

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, domc

Lets say I have the example code

```
kkk<-data.frame(m.mean=1:1000, m.sd=1:1000/20)
kkk[,3:502]<-NA

for (i in 1:nrow(kkk)){
  kkk[i,3:502]<-rnorm(n=500, mean=kkk[i,1], sd=kkk[i,2])
}
```

I would like to convert this function to run parallel with `doMC`. My problem is that `foreach` results in a list, whereas I need the results of each iteration to be a vector that can be then transfered to the data frame (which later will be exported as CVS for further processing).

Any ideas?

Comment: you want the `.combine` argument to `foreach`.  Take a look at `?foreach` and you can see examples.

Comment: i know the '.combine' argument, however as I see it this implies the creation of another vector (with the results) and then transfering the results into my initial data frame. Is it possible to save this step/time? (My data set is big and iterations in the scale of 100.000). Thanks

Comment: This seems like a good place to use `data.table`.

Comment: @Andrie Ok i see what you mean. I'll look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop for this, and putting a large matrix of numbers in a data frame only to treat is as a matrix is inefficient (although you may need to create a data frame at the end *after* doing all your math in order to write to a CSV file).

```
m.mean <- 1:1000
m.sd <- 1:1000/20
num.columns <- 500
x <- matrix(nrow=length(m.mean), ncol=num.columns, 
            data=rnorm(n=length(m.mean) * num.columns))
x <- x * cbind(m.sd)[,rep(1,num.columns)] + cbind(m.mean)[,rep(1,num.columns)]
kkk <- data.frame(m.mean=m.mean, m.sd=m.sd, unname(x))
write.csv(kkk, "kkk.txt")
```

To answer your original question about directly assigning results to an existing data structure from a foreach loop, that is not possible. The foreach package's parallel backends are designed to perform each computation in a separate R process, so each one has to return a separate object to the parent process, which collects them with the `.combine` function provided to foreach. You could write a parallel foreach loop that assignes directly to the `kkk` variable, but it would have no effect, because each assignment would happen in the separate processes and would not be shared with the main process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know i don't need a loop for the example provided. I just wrote it to present the case.